# Displaying text when Select Option is chosen. How to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to do it with hrefs and ids. It is not what I really need.

I need it this way:

```css
div.selectcountry {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  }
div.countrydepartment {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="selectcountry">Choose your country: <select>
  <option>Russia</option>
  <option>China</option>
  <option>Tajikistan</option>
  </select></div>
  
<div class="countrydepartment">Here should be a text dependingly on which country is chosen.<br>
— Russian department: +7 (000) 000 00 00<br>
— Chinese department: +86 (000) 000 00 00<br>
— Tajikistan department: +992 (000) 000 00 00<br>
</div>
```

This is an example of what I need: http://fms-nso.ru/departments/13/

How to do it? Maybe using JS? But how?
Explain me, please.

Thank you for your help and explanation!

Comment: Can you wrap the departments in ``div``?I.e. do you have an access to HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User jQuery's change event listener.

```js
$('.selectcountry select').change(function() {
  country = $(this).val();
  //reset
  $('.countrydepartment span').removeClass('active');
  //show current countrydepartment
  $('.countrydepartment span[country="' + country + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
div.selectcountry {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div.countrydepartment {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.countrydepartment span {
  display: none;
}
.countrydepartment span.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectcountry">
  Choose your country:
  <select>
    <option selected disabled>--- Select Your Country ---</option>
    <option value='russia'>Russia</option>
    <option value='china'>China</option>
    <option value='tajikistan'>Tajikistan</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="countrydepartment">
  <span country='russia'>— Russian department: +7 (000) 000 00 00</span>
  <span country='china'>— Chinese department: +86 (000) 000 00 00</span>
  <span country='tajikistan'>— Tajikistan department: +992 (000) 000 00 00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, liked your version! Very clean. Thank you a lot. You helped me so much. Can I just put in first disabled option the title of the Select? Like <option>--- Select Your Country ---</option>

Comment: @ZafarGilfanov Sure! This way:

`<option value='selectone' disabled selected>--- Select Your Country ---</option>`

Comment: You know I insert this code to my CMS editor... It breaks my code..., which makes me sad :(

Answer (score 2):

You must add classes so you have a way to track the changing select:

```
<div class="selectcountry">Choose your country:
    <select class="selcountry">
        <option value='1'>Russia</option>
        <option value='2'>China</option>
        <option value='3'>Tajikistan</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="countrydepartment">Here should be a text dependingly on which country is chosen.
    <div id='countrycontacts'></div>
</div>
```

and your JavaScript/jQuery could look something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var cc = ['Russian department: +7 (000) 000 00 00', 'Chinese department: +86 (000) 000 00 00', 'Tajikistan department: +992 (000) 000 00 00'];
    $('.selcountry').change(function(e) {
        var country = $(this).val() - 1;
        var contactinfo = cc[country];
        $('#countrycontacts').html(contactinfo);
    });
});
```